# Find NDK usage in a project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have a project I didn't create. I need to find usages of the NDK so I can upgrade / stop crashes occurring in Android 7 related to

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

Is there a simple way to find the usages / fix this ?

Comment: Do you really need target level 24 or higher?

Comment: They will be in the 'jni' and 'libs' folders.